# Cordova ios platform version too high

Tags: ios, cordova, logging

I am having problems running the cordova project in the ios emulator. The `console.log` file does not exist. On Android it is working though. I think it is because of the version of my cordova ios platform, cause when I do:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console`

it says:

`Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 4.5.2, failed version requirement: <4.5.0`

So my version is too high and does not meet the requirement. What should I do? Should I downgrade it, if yes how can I do that?

Comment: you can switch to lower version for dev and re-install the newest for production (you are supposed to remove the console plugin for prod, it is not used). To do that type `cordova platform rm ios` to remove it, and for example `cordova platform add ios@4.5.0` (don't choose this version but the one just before as it is a strict `<`)

Answer (score 1):

Since cordova-ios 4.5.0 `cordova-plugin-console` is included in the cordova-ios base, you do not need this plugin anymore. You can read about it [here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/08/ios-release.html).
Check if there is this feature element in the config.xml:

```
<feature name="Console">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger"/>
  <param name="onload" value="true"/>
</feature>
```

If not you have to add it as a child of the ios platform tag to use `console.log()` and other console functions. You can comment it out for production builds.

Comment: OK, I have updated my cordova-ios again and no in the config.xml there is no feature tag under then `<platform name="ios">` tag. So I added your code snippet in the ios tag, but still no success...the output says `logPath: /Hello/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log` but there is no such file there...

Comment: It may be that it belongs outside of the ios platform tag, not entirely sure about that.

Comment: I dont think this is correct as the code snippet is already in `platforms/ios/HelloWorld/config.xml`. I.e. the platform config.xml :(

Comment: Then you can leave out the feature tag in your root config.xml, it should work without it. I did not know it is added by default.